# how to get all images from phone in ios

Tags: ios, swift, photos, phasset

I want to get all images from the phone.for create multiple selections in photos library.I am using below code to get all images from the phone. it's working perfectly but when on the phone have 1000 images its take more time to get all images and show on view.How to reduce the time of getting all images from the phone.

```
 // get all images from photos
    func getAllImagesFromPhotos() -> [Photos]?
    {

        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]

        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)

        var allImages = [Photos]()

        for index in 0..<fetchResult.count
        {
            let asset = fetchResult.object(at: index) as PHAsset
            imgManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width:200,height:200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (uiimage, info) in
                if let image = uiimage
                {
                    allImages.append(Photos(image: image, selected: false))
                }
            })
        }

        return allImages
    }
```

Comment: it makes sense that it'll take a long time to load all images, if you explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve there might be better ways to do the task, what are you trying to accomplish by getting all the pictures?

Comment: for select multiple images from photos

Comment: I think you are going to have to design your app around the idea it is going to take a long time to load a large number of images (It'll also take a lot of memory). Do you really need all of them loaded at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I want to load all images like whatsapp for user upload multiple images at one time

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel then, iOS has the UIImagePickerController class that does exactly that, it also loads images as user scrolls so it won't load everything at once causing that performance hit

Comment: So please tell me what I do ? UIImagePickerController only select one image at one time.I want to select multiple images at once.

Comment: I didn't see the part that you wanted to select multiple images :), will update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you want to actually batch the image loading, load 10 images at a time, and display them, when the user scrolls a bit more, load the next batch, etc..

if you load all images, then of course there will be an unavoidable performance hit.

what you want to use instead is the UIImagePickerController class from UIKit

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) is the documentation from apple on UIImagePickerController.

If you don't want to use UIImagePickerController, then you have to load a smaller set of images at a time and allow the users to "load more" by scrolling further on the selection view.

**EDIT: Multi image selection**

After reading your comment about wanting to select multiple images, it's clear that UIImagePickerController is made to select single images, however, you can just not dismiss it upon selection, and have a toast message saying "Image selected", when the user select an image, and not dismiss the view, allowing the user to select another image, etc.. if the user select the same image again, you may just show the toast again saying "Image removed" since you can verify if the image has already been selected from before.

if you don't want to implement that workaround, your only choice is to batch load images in smaller chunks of around 10 images or so as I recommended in the original answer.

however, If you really don't want to implement that yourself, i recommend using a 3rd party library, something like [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) for example, there are hundreds of other libraries that do just that.

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Rather than batching the loading of the images it would be much more sensible to use a UITableView or UICollectionView (depending on how they are displayed) and batching individual downloads in the background as required.  However as you say there are 3rd party libraries to do this kind of image caching if you don't want to develop your own.

Comment: Batching is better in this use case, it’ll give a smoother scrolling experience, as the table view will surely display more than one image at once , so it’s better to fetch more data than fetch it one by one which will probably cause an overhead, however loading in batches or one by one is still the correct answer rather than loading all at once :) so you’re not wrong either, it all depends on the required outcome

Comment: If you push the loading of an image onto a background thread and have it update the table (for example) when done (assuming the cell is still visible) it won't slow anything down at all.  In our app we can have 10,000s of products in our table with images and there is no slow down.  Obviously you have a placeholder image while waiting for the load but that's the same either way.  Also you can take advantage of pre-fetching to start the images loading even before they are visible.  However as you say it's down to how the app is setup and beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Absolutely true!, I have done similar work on an app that loaded an infinite set of images as you scroll , and it all boils down to properly configure GCD , I also did the placeholder thumbnail as you scroll and it waits for the image to load in the background before updating the image in the cell , in my case we did fetch 50 thumbs to minimize the chatter with the server. But on the phone directly it should be ok, I’m thinking slow downs on older devices and not modern phones

Comment: True if you are communicating with a server it does make more sense to batch in that case.  I was thinking more of accessing on the phone direct.  Our app downloads all images it requires in the background to be stored locally because it has to operate offline although there is also functionality to download as requested if needed but none of our customers ever use that.  Luckily it all works with our own custom developed cloud backend (using AWS) so we have control of all stages.